# How do I display same “proportional” text size on different resolutions?

Tags: directx, rendering, text

I draw some text on screen using ID3DXFont::DrawText. This text should be displayed the same regardless of screen resolution.

For example, if screen resolution is low, text wrapped and when it is higher text is not wrapped. How can I avoid such situation? I want text size to be connected to screen resolution so if resolution is lower I want the text to be relatively smaller so that no wrapping happens. Is there any way?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to manually get the size of the screen and scale down the requested text size.

Comment: Hello again, this solved my problem. I just wanted to share, Thanks :)